# CV redox peaks and Gamry Potentiometer

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm using Gamry Potentiometer for taking CV measurements for finding the appropriate voltage values for oxidation/reduction peaks and Echem Analyst for analyzing. CV measurements has performed on liquid electrolyte in order to find if working electrode accept Li ions. My question is about interpreting the results.

How can I interpret if potential difference equal or below 1V has no oxidation or reduction peak (or has only one of them) while potential sweep between -2V to 2V bring good results but if I change it to 1 to -3 no reduction peak again. Moreover, going to negative values has a bad consequences such broke the working electrode. What does it mean going to negative values?

That was my first question, my second question is: Is it possible perform Chronoamperometry measurements (in other word, simulate) by using existing CV measurements via Echem analyst script editor?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).